# Difference between if (var.length >0){} and if (var){}

Tags: javascript, variables

In javascript is there a difference between using

```
if (foo.length > 0) {
//run code involving foo
}
```

and

```
if (foo) {
//run code involving foo
}
```

If so, could someone please explain the difference and an example where they would not be the same?

Comment: Did you mean to compare `if (foo.length)` and `if (foo.length > 0)`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an example where they are not the same:

```
var x = [];
alert(x? 'yes' : 'no'); // displays "yes"
alert((x.length > 0)? 'yes' : 'no'); // displays "no"
```

Answer (score 2):

The two are completely different.  I'm assuming by the use of `.length` that `var` is a jquery object, in which case `if(var)` will always be true.  jQuery will always return an object, but it may be empty.  `if(var.length>0)` checks that the jquery object actually contains an element.

Answer (score 1):

The former tests if var.length returns more than 0.  The latter tests if the value of var is true.

You cannot necessarily use either one for all variables.  For a boolean, if(var) makes more sense.  For a string or array, if(var.length) makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

they're obviously different, the question is really just why are they different.

your first example is explictly checking that the length property of an object is greater than 0. if that is true it evaluates the content of the if statement.

the second example can only tell you if the variable is 'truthy', or 'falsy' (or as the great stephen colbert coined it, 'truthiness').  check out the [wikipedia article on javascript booleans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Boolean) for detail.